# How to take two path variable in Twisted framework?

Tags: url, twisted, path-variables

I would like to have two path variables. The url pattern looks like this:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<path_var_1>/<path_var_2>
```

where ***path_var_1*** & ***path_var_2*** are dynamic. I can take one as instructed [here](https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-15.1.0/web/howto/web-in-60/dynamic-dispatch.html) but how can I get two or more?

Comment: I suppose you're using Twisted Web? and the Resource API?  Have you tried anything so far?  What is the *goal* you're trying to achieve by consuming two segments at once instead of just one?

Comment: @Paul, Sorry for late. Actually, I was working with CoAP protocol for one of my project. For this project I am using `txThings` which was built on top `Twisted framework`. For a certain URI request I had to handle two parameters (resource ID & item). I had to parameterized these either with path variables or query string or mix of those. I was able to take one parameter. I was looking for both into the URL. How I can have two parameters in a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idiomatic way to consume multiple path segments with Twisted Web's resource abstraction (upon which the txThings resource abstraction appears to be built) is to have more than one resource.  Resources corresponding to earlier parts of the path gather up state and pass it along to resources corresponding to later parts of the path.

For example

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class Root(Resource):
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return FirstSegment(name)


class FirstSegment(Resource):
    def __init__(self, first):
        self.first = first
        Resource.__init__(self)

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return SecondSegment(self.first, name)

class SecondSegment(Resource):
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
        Resource.__init__(self)

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "Handling {first}/{second}".format(
            first=self.first,
            second=self.second,
        )

root = Root()
site = Site(root)
...
```

Another option is to use "leaf" resources which stop traversal even if there are more path segments in the request:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class HandleItAll(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "Handling {path}".format(path="/".join(request.postpath))

root = HandleItAll()
site = Site(root)
...
```

Comment: +1 for isLeaf part (works fine). By the way, for upper part I'm getting `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`. @Jean-Paul can you explain a bit more in detail why I am getting this error (for the first part)?

Comment: As I understood, `FirstSegment` class in `root = FirstSegment()` requires one more argument. Do I miss something here?

Comment: Yes, you're right - my mistake.  I've edited the example to fix this.

Comment: Getting "No Such Resource No such child resource."

Comment: When doing what?

Comment: for both 

- `http://localhost:8880/foo/bar`
- `http://localhost:8880/foo/bar/`

Comment: Sorry.  childFactory is the Nevow method.  It's getChild in Twisted Web.  Updating answer.